# LAMP - PHP save files, but browser does not read

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, localhost, lamp

Images saved by PHP are linked to the www-data user, and therefore are not read by the browser unless I run it in ROOT mode. However, if I open a terminal and use CHOWN or CHMOD, I can solve this manually. But I do not plan to do this every time I upload an image.
Is there a way to make PHP save the images correctly? ie belonging to ROOT or my user?

Below is a portion of the directory listing. As soon as the file wi_10026.png' has been saved. Notice that the owner is different. This causes the browser to not be allowed to execute it.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  27150 Jan  2 14:44 wi_10026.png
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root     root      43007 Set 11  2014 wi_cadeado.png
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root     root      15603 Dez 23 18:39 wi_expirou.png
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root     root      12139 Nov 16  2015 wi_guarda.png
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root     root      13960 Out 20 23:50 wi_livro.png
```

Comment: Your webserver should have no trouble with files owned by `www-data` as it presumably runs as that user itself. When you say *browser* do you mean a *file browser* like FTP or something, instead of the *web* browser?

Comment: The files are world-readable, so any user should be able to read them.

Comment: `rwxrwxrwx root:root` is bad.

Comment: My browser is Chromium v. 43.0.2357.81.